# Need to stop "Changed database context to 'DB_Name'" from popping up

Tags: sql-server-2005, delphi-xe7

I am getting "*Changed database context to..*" message when USE statement is used.Application is built using Delphi XE7. I need to modify the databases in between without trying to get this message.Other database which i need is tempDB.Is there any SQL statement to pass from code to stop this message from coming?

Comment: Which db access components are you using, the Ado ones such as TAdoQuery or what? If I set a TAdoQuery's Sql to "use pubs select * from authors" and then call AdoQuery.Open, the rows of the Authors table are returned without any message such as the one you quote ...

Comment: Please add to your q the **exact** delphi code which triggers the error **and** the Sql you are executing when it occurs.  If you can't provide these details, I think the question should be closed because it can't be answered.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Solved the issue by adding a condition when displaying error messages so that this message will not be displayed.Code used:"if not E.LastMessage.Contains('Changed database context to') then"